# how to prevent mysqli_fetch_object to overwrite null values in left join

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

I have two tables in mysql which one of them is parent of another table.

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    `a_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `b` (
    `b_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `a_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `stuffs` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`b_id`)
);
```

As it's obvious the relation between two tables is 1-N and table 'b' might has record for any record in table 'a' and might has not.

And in cases that table 'b' has no record for some records in table 'a' and I join this tables using this query :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE a LEFT JOIN TABLE b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
```

And then use `mysqli_fetch_object` to fetch record's object it will replace `a.a_id` with `b,a_id` which is `NULL`

How can I prevent it except using `SELECT` in query?

Is there any way in php and mysqli functions to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Select columns with unique aliases

```
SELECT 
a.a_id,
b.a_id as b_a_id
,a.name
,b.b_id
,b.stuffs
 FROM 
TABLE a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
```

query having the same names of columns the last column will be picked so want if you want to access `a_id` of table a you need to use different alias for the `a_id` column of table b

Comment: Thank you, but I had forgotten to determine any way except using select in query.

Comment: Something I just encountered, if you got `SELECT *,
a.a_id,
b.a_id as b_a_id`, it won't work. The * is overruling it.